# Angular2 - EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'af' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, auth0, angularfire2

I'm building an Angular2 app using Auth0 for authentication and AngularFire for my database. In my constructor, I passed my AngularFire af instance, but I can't access it inside my callback event. Is there another way to access my AngularFire instance?

```
// app/auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AngularFire, AuthMethods, AuthProviders } from 'angularfire2';


// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;
declare var Auth0: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
 // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID', 'AUTH0_DOMAIN', {});


  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event

    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error:any, profile:any){
        if(error){
          throw new Error(error);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));

        var options = {
        id_token : authResult.idToken,
        api : 'firebase',
        scope : 'openid name email displayName',
        target: 'AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'
        };


        var auth0 = new Auth0({domain:'AUTH0_DOMAIN', clientID:'AUTH0_CLIENT_ID' });
        auth0.getDelegationToken(options, function(err, result){

          if(!err){


            this.af.auth.login(result.id_token, {
              provider: AuthProviders.Custom,
              method: AuthMethods.CustomToken
            });
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your `this` inside callback function points to that function. You have three options:

1. Save this of class: `let that = this` and use `that.af` inside callback.
2. Use lambda, because it doesn't change `this`: `(error, profile) => {...}`
3. You can call `.bindTo(this)` to function and bind this to class

Also, I recommend lambda approach.

Comment: Thanks, I spent days trying to figure out what the issue was.